# welcome page loads when Allow in incognito is checked/unchecked in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extensions.I used [chrome.runtime.onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) to load a html page whenever the extension is installed or updated.But when i am testing it in chrome, whenever i check/uncheck Allow in incognito the same html page loads each time.How to avoid this behaviour? I used "incognito":"split" in manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish you'd posted the code so I could try to replicate the problem and give a specific solution but the easy solution is to use [chrome storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to save the extension's version when welcome.html is opened and compare it to the current version next time onInstalled is fired.

If the stored version is the same don't open it. If it's undefined or older, open it.

Get your extension's version by extracting it from chrome.extension.getURL("manifest.json")

**Edit:**
After a bit of googling it seems you can access the manifest more directly. Get the version number using the code below.

```
var version = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
```

**Edit:**
It seems the previous version is supplied in the callback when you update so you don't need to store anything. The object provided can be compared to the current version using chrome.runtime.getManifest().version

Something like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    if(details.reason === "install"){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "welcome.html"});  
    }
    else if(details.reason === "update"){
        var currentVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
        var previousVersion = details.previousVersion;

        if(previousVersion !== currentVersion){
            chrome.tabs.create({url: "welcome.html"}); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah you are correct fetch manifest version number and check it with the stored value from local storage will do the task.But why chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {window.open("welcome.html","_self"); }); opens a new the html page when i check/uncheck the allow incognito option?

Comment: After a bit of experimenting it seem that's just what it does. The runtime documentation doesn't explain it. Google seems to understand what you want to do as they provide previousVersion in the object supplied Object {previousVersion: "1.0.7", reason: "update"} which you can just compare to the current version using getManifest().version. I don't see any other reason why they'd supply it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. I assume that when you uncheck "Allow in incognito", Chrome nukes the local state of the (split) incognito instance.

Comment: chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
 if(details.reason == "install")
    window.open("welcome.html","_self");
});

No problem with the above code it works fine.But if I use (details.reason=="install" || details.reason=="update") then the welcome page opens on check/uncheck.